# Suggested Edits Summary from My Account Page

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Is it possible to see a status of my suggested edits (i.e. *user had X edit suggestions approved, and Y edit suggestions rejected*; for reputation below 2,000) and a list of edited questions from "My Account" page?

I know that Stack Overflow keeps track of suggested edits including list of approvals and rejections (if one goes to an edited question and clicks *suggested* in reviews list) but I am not sure if it is possible to see summary of those in My Account page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, go to [your `activity` tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity), click "All actions" in the right sidebar, then go to the last tab, to see a list of all your suggestions:

[image: screenshot of suggested edits]

To get statistics on your suggestion approvals and rejections, click on a `suggested` link; you may have to expand the stats area with a `(more)` link:

[image: Suggested edit stats]

Here the stats area has been expanded, so the `(more)` link is now a `(less)` link instead.

Comment: Ah! Too obvious to check that tab :). Many thanks for your help.