# Where are approved edits listed in SO?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I'm trying to find out if there is a place in my SO user account info/settings where I can consult the list and count of my approved edits.

So far I've found all my approved and rejected edits under: **SO user account >> activity >> suggestions** tab.

Is there any place or filter to see the list and count of approved edits only? Is this a feature that will appear as I grow in reputation (I'm currently below 600)?

Comment: See [Suggested Edits Summary from My Account Page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160393/160394#160394)

Comment: There is no option to filter your suggested edits by status, at most you can get statistics on how many have been approved or rejected.

Comment: `henser had 52 edit suggestions approved, and 15 edit suggestions rejected`  Is seen from any suggested edit you're involved in by clicking "more".

Comment: Missed that more/less link over there. Thanks to you both. That solved it. Cheers